# How to integrate FB login with my own server

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm not understanding FB is saying we can use FB login in place of my own server's login.  More like how Uber allows a user to login using FB.

How is the flow supposed to go?  Is it like this?

1. User clicks login using FB on my Mobile App and grants permission
2. User informs my server that it has logged into Facebook.
3. ??? what happens here?  How is security handled here?

The reason I ask is because FB doesn't say how the server side is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. User clicks login using FB on my Mobile App and grants permission. You will get a access_token.
2. User informs my server that it has logged into Facebook with received token
3. The server requests FB via that token, and get information.
4. The server responds to the client success or not.

Comment: How do you solve scenarios where a user would try to create an account after, should we try to link that account to the account created using fb login?

Comment: Yes, you can link it with fb acc. But I think it complicated. I will try to let user edit their profile (fb acc), like name or adding password. Because after fetched the infos from fb, I added them to database. Then user can edit them.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use information associated with facebook to create a user on your server.

So..

1. User clicks login using FB on mobile and grants permission
2. Use info that you get from FB to create a user account (username, email, token) by calling your server endpoint.
3. Next time user logs in, you know who they are.

FB step is just shortcut for asking there email/password. It also allows for easy sharing of your content.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, The process is

User Signs in, using your facebook SDK (with your App facebook client Id linked) and then on success returns:
User Information including:

- Profile Picture
- Email Address
- Full Name

as **email address is already verified by fb**, so you can trust this email address to be true.

Now you can register user in your own server for signing in directly using your sign in page, by using the response email address. Simply provide a option to set password.(better to be kept optional)

Also fb sdk return **access_token**, which can be used further to call graph api's by your server or app.